# How can I generate a nested array in foreach loop to produce the same result? Telegram PHP Bot

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-telegram-bot

This code snippet:

```
$inline_keyboard = new InlineKeyboard([
    ['text' => 'valueA', 'callback_data' => 'valueA'],
], [
    ['text' => 'valueB', 'callback_data' => 'valueB'],
]);
```

produces in my telegramm bot the following inline keyboard:

[image: telegram output]

So far so good... But instead of hardcoding the values, I want to produce the same output with values from an array (database query).

I tried with something like this:

```
$dbValues = array("valueA", "valueB");

foreach ($dbValues as $value)
{
    $inline_keyboard .= new InlineKeyboard([
        ['text' => "$value", 'callback_data' => "$value"],
    ]);
}
```

But this fails... I think because I don't have to run a "new" instance in each iteration?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenation object like string. you can go another way, build the array, and after send array to InlineKeyboard

```
$dbValues = array("valueA", "valueB");
foreach ($dbValues as $value)
{
    $inline_keyboard[] = [['text' => "$value", 'callback_data' => "$value"]];
}

$inline_keyboard = new InlineKeyboard(...$inline_keyboard);
```

Further details see ["New Keyboard structure and how to pass dynamic arguments"](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/wiki/New-Keyboard-structure-and-how-to-pass-dynamic-arguments) from the php-telegram-bot wiki.

Comment: It is almost what I have searched for. But I think the nesting is now not correct. The inline keyboard buttons are now horizontaly not verticaly scaled... see: https://imgur.com/a/2xaORWj

Comment: I get this error: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in .../vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Entities/Entity.php on line 41
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\InlineKeyboard::$inline_keyboard in .../vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Entities/Keyboard.php on line 42
PHP message: PHP Warning:  array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in .../vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Entities/Keyboard.php on line 42"

Comment: If you wan't to study the entities you can find them here: https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/tree/master/src/Entities

Answer (score 0):

To get a horizontal keyboard you can use this code snippet:

```
$dbValues = array("valueA", "valueB");
foreach ($dbValues as $value)
{
    $inline_keyboard[] = ['text' => "$value", 'callback_data' => "$value"];
}

$inline_keyboard = new InlineKeyboard($inline_keyboard);
```